# Unsafe javascript attempt to access frame (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Site here http://thomaspalumbo.com/tests/

Code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function playSound() {
    var sounds = new Array(
                "bells.mp3"
                  );
 $('#soundDiv').html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()*         (sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
return false;
};

</script>

</head>

<body>



<button onclick="javascript:playSound()">Button</button>
 <div id="soundDiv"></div>
```

Any help? I get this error generally when I click the button and the sound is still playing.  Also I can't get the button to perform the function without reloading the page. In other words I don't want the page to reload.

Comment: Looking at the console loading your page, I see attempts to access the main frame page from embedded content from `dsnextgen.com`. I can't see from a quick look at the DOM where this content is. Googling for `dsnextgen.com` leads to reports of malware via hijacking, so it is worth looking into the possibility that your homepage has been hacked.

Comment: Something is definitely trying to show ads on your page, but the ads aren't appearing. Looking at the source for your main .html page shows nothing that indicates ads on the page are intended, so this could well be a hijacking. The question is where is the malicious code coming from? The most likely candidate seems to be a trojan in the local `jquery.jplayer.min.js` script; but if that is the case it is very well hidden.

Comment: @JimBlackler, or inside the `mp3` file.

Comment: Looking a bit further, it seems that what happens is the hijacking content is itself iframing your content. Possibly the default page on your domain has been redirected elsewhere. This could actually be what is breaking your code.

Comment: I removed the source to the infected plugin and all is well now. Curious though is there anyway to have the function play a new sound file if the button is clicked during a sound playing. As of now I get an error and the sound stops.

Comment: I'm still seeing this hijack attempt on your test page.

Comment: I used a different browser after I removed the source to the plugin. Did you clear the cache or try a new browser?

Comment: No doubt... cache is clear but the problem is still there.

Comment: The focus of this question should be on _one_ thing.  Either the hijacking attempt or how to properly use the sound plugin.

Comment: hmm. That's strange. Firefox shows no problems. I was under the impression the hijacking had been solved. Let's fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site was hijacked by `dsnextgen.com`, so you're going to have to fix that first.   This is the console error...

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://thomaspalumbo.com/tests/ from frame with URL
>   http://dsnextgen.com/?domainname=thomaspalumbo.com&a_id=101686&session_token=AG06ipBDokkZI0hxmF11k0IzVtiy5sNPSQoTCJHXlb-U6LMCFXPptgodkXEANRgEcTdmdWKwHHoDeMvy4LMC.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Since this error only pops up when clicking the button multiple times, I'd try a different `mp3` file to see if this error goes away.

More info:  [http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan:JS/IframeRef](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?Name=Trojan%3aJS/IframeRef)

---

BTW:  It's jQuery, so I'd leverage that power to get rid of the inline JavaScript.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function playSound() {
            var sounds = new Array(
                "bells.mp3"
            );
            $('#soundDiv').html("<embed src=\""+sounds[Math.floor(Math.random()* (sounds.length+1))]+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" />");
            return false;
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button').click(function() {
                playSound();
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <button>Button</button>
    <div id="soundDiv"></div>
```